# Call php class method from android application with parameters

Tags: php, android

Is it possible to call this php function from an android application?

```
<?PHP
namespace TEST
{
    class NameOfClass
    {
         public function InsertAccount($firstname, $lastname)
         {
              ...
         }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes. It is. Want more information? Please provide more information.

Comment: It is possible as long as you make an HTTP request.

Comment: I need some more information about this call to php from android. Is there a tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do that:
Create a php file that contains your method. Note that in this case our file accepts POST request only:

file: **my-method.php**

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        //Request Data comes in JSON format from the android app
        $json_request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $json_result = array();

        //Get name from $json_request variable
        $name = $json_request->{"name"};

        //Your method
        sayHi($name);

    }

    function sayHi($name){

        echo "Hello " . $name;

    }

?>
```

In your android app, make an HTTP request to your php file as follows

**Inner class inside your activity**

```
private class CheckName extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String apiUrl;
        private String name;

        public CheckName(String apiUrl, String name) {

            this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
            this.name = name;

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                // HTTP Client
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(apiUrl);

                // DATA TO SEND
                JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
                request.put("name", name);

                // ENTITY
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(request.toString());

                // PARAMS
                httpPost.setEntity(se);
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                // RESPONSE
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                // RESULT DATA
                result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            //The result that you get should be: Hello Joe
            return result;

        }

    }
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT:**
This is how you implement it on your app

```
 CheckName user = new CheckName("http://my-domain-name.com/my-method.php", "Joe");
 user.execute();
```